# How to increase duration for multiple documents in mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have many documents in a collection of mongoDB. I want to increase the `start_dateTime` field by the given duration in minutes and the given `user_id`.

But that collection contains multiple documents for the given `user_id`. So I want to increase all  `start_dateTime` by the given duration and the given `user_id`.

I got the following error

> MongoError: Cannot increment with non-numeric argument:
>   {start_datetime: new Date(1570701481175)}

```
function delayworkTime(req,res,next)
{
    const usrId = req.body.user_id;
    var delays_by = req.body.delays_by;

    try
    {
        Works.updateMany(   {user_id: usrId},
                                {$inc: {start_datetime : moment().add(delays_by, 'minutes')}}
                            )
                            .then(function (delays) 
                            {
                            console.log(delaysss);})
                            .catch(function (err)
                            {
                                console.error(err);
                            });
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: `$inc` will increment only on integer not on date.

Comment: Then how can I update the date, please ?